# Add custom fields for use in template

Tags: bigcommerce

Currently custom fields show up as text on product pages.

*Custom Field #1 Name: Material, Custom Field #1 Value: Cotton*

[image: Custom field]

Is there some other option instead to just pass data to the template?  For example I'd like to display a 'NEW' label on the product page if new == true.

Sort of like https://springmerchant.com/bigcommerce/product-labels/

Right now we're using handlebars and if-statements to hide custom fields with a `__`prefix.  For example `__new: true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing your template in stencil, there are a couple of options... You can loop through the custom fields until you find the correct one and then check the value... Ex:

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
{{#if name "==" "__new"}}
{{#if value "==" "true"}}
YOUR HTML CODE HERE
{{/if}}
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Alternatively, you can put all your custom_fields into an array and use javascript to populate various aspects of the site:

```
<script>
var custom = [];
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
custom.push({'name':"{{name}}",'value':"{{value}}"});
{{/each}}

YOUR CODE TO LOOP THROUGH JSON ARRAY AND DO VARIOUS TESTS AND STUFF
</script>
```

If you don't have access to stencil templates and are just doing development through the control panel, you could write javascript to parse the default custom_field html and then use the data accordingly.

None of the solutions are particularly clean, but they all work.